# How to connect Xamarin forms to mysql data base

Tags: mysql, xamarin.forms

I want to create a class which connect 
to a mysql Server to all platform (IOS Android and windows)

how can I do that? is there a DLL or an API to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not connect your App directly to your database. This will cause a huge secruity problem. Use web services instead. The web services will handle the interaction between your client and server.

[Web Services](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/)

And if you are just playing around or sth here is an example.

[Example](https://components.xamarin.com/view/mysql-plugin)